# type casting not working in 3.5 as in 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class Foo : Entity
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
}


//foos is an IEnumerable<Foo> with List<Foo> value

foos as IEnumerable<Entity> //works in .net 4.0, doesn't work in 3.5,
```

how to get a similar behaviour in 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As JoDG points out, this is enabled by the new co-variance feature in c#4 - the closest you can get in c#3 is:

```
IEnumerable<Entity> entities = foos.Cast<Entity>();
```

Comment: too bad my foos is boxed as object so I can't really use cast

Comment: @Omu - In that case you'll have to cast it first: `((IEnumerable<Foo>)foos).Cast<Entity>()`.

Comment: well it's not always IEnumerable<Foo> sometimes it's IEnumerable<Bar> or some other inheriter of Entity

Comment: @Omu - In that case cast to the non-generic `IEnumerable` since `Cast<T>` is defined on that.

Answer (score 7):

This construct relies on covariance/contravariance which was introduced in .net 4.0. You will not be able to get this to work on earlier versions.

Here's a nice article about it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Comment: isn't there any other way around this, I just want the same result, doesn't matter how

Comment: @Omu: see the answer of Lee: `IEnumerable<Entity> entities = foos.Cast<Entity>();`

Answer (score 1):

without Co/Contravariance you have to cast yourself:

```
var entities = foos.Cast<Entity>(); // yields IEnumerable<Entity>
```